# R CMD defaults to R version selection screen in Linux terminal

Tags: r, linux, installation, command-line, package

When I enter `R CMD ...` in my Linux terminal, I receive a dialog to choose the version of R I'd like to run:

```
$ R CMD
Available Versions:
------------------------
3.4.0
3.4.1
3.4.2
3.4.4
3.5.0
3.5.1
3.5.2
3.5.3
3.6.0
3.6.1
4.0.2
Enter The R Version You'd Like To Run:
```

Is there an easy fix to this from the command line?

#### Issue recognized by @MrFlick below

The choice of R versions comes from a non-standard wrapper around the R command:

```
$ which R
alias R='/opt/rVersionSelect.sh'
        /opt/rVersionSelect.sh
```

Here is the script, in which you can see the selection mechanism:

```
$ head -500 /opt/rVersionSelect.sh
#!/bin/bash

RDIR=/opt/R

echo "Available Versions:"
echo "------------------------"

for rVer in $RDIR/* ; do
    echo $(echo $rVer | cut -d- -f2)
done

read -n 5 -p "Enter The R Version You'd Like To Run: " RunThisVersion

if [ -d $RDIR/R-$RunThisVersion/ ] ; then
    echo "Loading $RunThisVersion...."
    wait 10
    clear
    $RDIR/R-$RunThisVersion/bin/R --interactive
else
    echo "Unrecognized Version: $RunThisVersion"
fi
```

As it turns out, the `R` in `R CMD` needs to point to one of the many R versions installed. For example, `/opt/R/R-3.5.3/bin/R CMD`.

Comment: That seems very odd. That's not the normal behavior for `R CMD`. What does `which R` return? Do you have some non-standard wrapper around the `R` command?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I figured out the solution below. From `which R` I get `alias R='/opt/rVersionSelect.sh'`. Yes, there is a non-standard wrapper around the R command. I'll place that in the original question post.

Comment: What what you are describing isn't how R is installed on most systems. You must have some non-standard install. It's unclear how your system has been configure so it's not clear who else would run into the problem. The "solution" you provide would not work for most. It would be nice to clarify exactly in what cases this is necessary. Where did `rVersionSelect.sh` come from? Is that a script you wrote?

Comment: Really the problem is that wrapper is poorly written and doesn't seem to account for non-interactive calls to R such as `R CMD`. It's unclear where that wrapper came from but the problem is there, and not with R itself. Perhaps consult your systems administrator to find recommended work arounds.

Comment: `rVersionSelect.sh` was placed there by admins, and I don't have admin rights. I agree that a better script should be able to accommodate exceptions, like `R CMD`.

Answer (score 0):

For the `R` in `R CMD`, it looks like I need to point to one of the many installations of R. For example, `/opt/R/R-3.5.3/bin/R CMD INSTALL rJava` gives me the same result in the Terminal as using **Build**, **Install and Restart** in Rstudio.

When I try to write a custom build script like `R CMD javareconf`, it fails to execute in RStudio. But `/opt/R/R-3.5.3/bin/R CMD javareconf` successfully executes in the Terminal.

Answer (score -1):

The way I've dealt with it is to go into the RStudio instance, open a project, and **Configure Build Tools**. Then I could achieve the same objectives using options from the **Build** menu. I think this question has merit, because difficult R package installations will suggest using `R CMD ...` to make the installation work.